# Use ProgressRing

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

**HI!. I have a problem**

```
<Button Margin="5"
        Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleProgressRing, Converter={StaticResource InvertBoolToVisibilityConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}">
        Content="Search"
</Button>

<mahApps:ProgressRing Margin="5"
                      Height="32" Width="32"
                      DockPanel.Dock="Right"
                      IsActive="{Binding IsActiveProgressRing, Mode=TwoWay}" 
                      Visibility="{Binding IsVisibleProgressRing, Mode=TwoWay}"/>
```

**i have too**

```
public class InvertBoolToVisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
{
    private readonly BooleanToVisibilityConverter _converter = new BooleanToVisibilityConverter();

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = _converter.Convert(value, targetType, parameter, culture) as Visibility?;
        return result == Visibility.Collapsed ? Visibility.Visible : Visibility.Collapsed;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var result = _converter.ConvertBack(value, targetType, parameter, culture) as bool?;
        return result != true;
    }
}
```

**In VM have**

```
private bool _isActiveProgressRing;

private Visibility _isVisibleProgressRing = Visibility.Collapsed;

IsActiveProgressRing = true;

IsVisibleProgressRing = Visibility.Visible;

.....................
.....................
<!-- SEARCH IN DB -->
.....................
.....................

IsVisibleProgressRing = Visibility.Collapsed;

IsActiveProgressRing = false;
```

**I need it is that when I look for in a database, the search button is hidden and the "ProgressRing" visible and active. When the search is over, everything returns to normal.
The problem is that the "progressRing" appears at the end of the search in the database and the button, never disappears.**

Comment: You need to put search code into background thread. Look at tasks or BackgroundWorker.

Answer (score 1):

If you are running the database search off the UI thread (in other words, the method is being called due to a button click or other GUI control event), it will make the GUI unresponsive and not update properly while the UI thread is occupied with the database search.

The database search should be moved to a background thread like Dennis suggested and, if need be, the background thread can update the GUI using this sort of construct to instruct the GUI thread to handle the desired GUI change (the background thread should never try to update the GUI directly):

```
this.Invoke((MethodInvoker)delegate {
    // this next line will run on the UI thread regardless of which thread called .Invoke()
    someLabel.Text = numDbResults.ToString() + " database matches found";
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Could you explain a little more how to use this code.
That piece of code you have to incorporate into the "VM"? Or inside the file dataAccess it is where I make the query to the database? This is called the dataaccess from the VM

`_empleadosDataAccess = new EmpleadosDataAccess ();

Employees = new ObservableCollection <Employee> (_ empleadosDataAccess.CoincidenciasDeEmpleados (FiltroDeBusqueda));`

I tried with

this.Invoke ((MethodInvoker) delegate {

     // SQL QUERY

});

But there is an error in "Invoke"

Comment: You will need to move the database query into a background thread; there's no way around that. But _from the database query background thread_, you could use that code snippet to safely make changes to the UI. For example, to re-enable the Search button right before the background thread exits (after it has completed its search),